# Why are the past and present tenses of "read" spelt the same?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, past-tense, present-tense

and only have different pronunciations?

Comment: I think you mean past and present tenses, e.g "I read" could, when written, be either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably not easy to answer exactly why this happened (past and present being identical in spelling), because I don't think anyone ever set out to do things this way.  Like most standard English words, *read* was not always spelled this way.  The OED lists, for example, *rædde, redis, redys, reeds, reids, redds, reed, red, redd*, etc. over the course of written English history.  The OED does briefly touch on the past/present spelling issue:

> The present-day spelling of the past tense and past participle forms is analogous to the present tense; the spelling *red* for past tense and past participle is found only in isolated instances in the modern period and was perhaps avoided because it coincided with the standard spelling of *red* adj.

To me, that is not a terribly satisfying answer, but it could be the correct one.