# Is 'read' the only word that has the same conjugation with different pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling-pronunciations

The past and present tenses of "read" are spelt the same but have different pronunciation. This question is related to the post [Why are the past and present tenses of "read" spelt the same?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/why-are-the-past-and-present-tenses-of-read-spelt-the-same).

Comment: Are you limiting this to verbs? To present and past tenses? WHat do you mean by "same conjugation"?

Comment: How do you pronounce *"live like Lazarus"*? Although this is a verb and an adjective, rather than two different forms of the same verb.

Comment: @Susan, sorry for the confusion. I was being very imprecise. I guess what I want to see is an example that if you see the sentence, say 'I read a book.', you cannot tell the exact meaning of it unless someone reads it. Does this help to explain my question?

Comment: @PeterShor, that is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The second basic form of "to read" keeps the a to differentiate it from "red", the colour.

Your use of the term conjugation is very unclear. A conjugation is a table of all the forms a verb can take. All finite forms in active and passive
and all infinite forms.

Answer (score 1):

Some people apparently pronounce the past tense of the word *beat* as /bɛt/ ("bet"); see the following question: [How common is pronouncing the past tense of beat as /bet/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169797)

The standard spelling for both the present and the past tense is "beat"—as far as I know, this doesn't change for people who use the pronunciation /bɛt/ for the past tense.

The existence of accents that use the pronunciation /bɛt/ for the past tense of *beat* does not seem to be widely known among speakers who use the pronunciation /biːt/ for both past and present tense.

Tetsujin's answer to the ELL question "[Can I say 'I sleeped all night' instead of slept?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/172151)" mentions the word *treat*; apparently, this has a past-tense form /trɛt/ for some speakers, although its usual spelling is unclear to me. Tetsujin writes that "Northern Br Eng still uses 'treat' [pronounced tret] as the past tense, even though Southern Br Eng would use 'treated' [tree-ted]", but the OED entry for *treat* seems to indicate that the spelling "tret" has been used for this verb form ("15–16 *Sc.* **treat**, 15– *Sc.* and *northern dialect* **tret**").